# Error in getting address of variable using ctypes.addressof in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

In below example, I try to get address of m variable but it show error

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> m = 1
>>> ctypes.addressof(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invalid type
>>>
>>>
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> 
>>> a = A()
>>> 
>>> ctypes.addressof(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invalid type
```

Answer (score 2):

What you've passed to `addressof` is not a variable, it is a Python `int` object in the first example and an `A` object in the second example. `addressof` only works on [ctypes `_CData`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#data-types).

I suggest reading [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to learn how Python doesn't have the concept of "variable" you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the address of the variable using the following command:

```
id(m)
#Example Output : 51148608
```

To get it using hex style use:

```
hex(id(m))
#Output: 0x30c7740
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, using `id` to find the address is [*a CPython implementation detail*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 0):

`ctypes.addressof` can only get the address of a `ctypes` type:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> m = c_int(1)
>>> addressof(m)
56017424
```

Comment: How I can get address of class objects  `A()` or list,

Comment: In CPython, id() does (but it's in general not guaranteed to). Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: That address returned from `id()` in CPython is an implementation detail, and is the address of a PyObject-derived instance. That's an opaque structure so the usefulness of the address is suspect.

Comment: @YannVernier I am trying to write the test cases for singleton class.

Comment: Then you can check with `a is b`, which effectively performs `id(a) == id(b)`.